# Marketing Cloud Exit Criteria for Converted Lead

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm very new to Marketing Cloud and I can't figure out how to remove a Lead from a Journey when it is converted.

This Journey only should have Leads in a certain Status. So I set the exit criteria as exit if Status is not equal to "Attempted Contact" OR IsConverted = TRUE.

If I move the Lead Status to any other Status other than the "Attempted Contact", it removes the Lead just fine. The issue is when a Lead is converted.

Technically, when a Lead is converted, the status changes, so the Status condition should be enough, but it doesn't work.

I hope I explained the use case good enough, but let me know if any other details are needed.

Thank you for the help!!

Ernesto

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an attribute group where your journey data source DE links to a copy Lead DE with a 1:1 relationship and set the exit criteria using contact data (contact datathe attribute group), then you can put "IsConverted = true" there.

Hence, whenever a Lead is converted, it will be removed from the journey.

References:

Make a copy lead DE: leverage Synchronized data extension and automation to make it up-to-date.

- [Synchronized data extension](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_creating_and_interacting_with_synchronized_data_sources.htm&type=5)
- [SQL query](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_use_the_sql_query_activity.htm&type=5)

Create an attribute group, so you can use for your exit criteria

- [Create attribute group](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_create_an_attribute_group.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thank you so much Duc! I'll try this and let you know how it goes.